# RecyclerView shows the borderd textview only after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an `arrayList` of books. It contains the book name and book tags (say history, novel, story etc.). I have used `RecyclerView` for listing. It works fine but the problem is that here tags are showing like text in the box.

[image: This is row]

Sometimes tags are not showing at the initial loading. after scrolling tags get displayed.

I don't know whats happening in the code. I think the issue is with the `RecyclerView`. I am setting thet visibility to `VISIBLE` in `onBindViewHolder`  still didnt get.

here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tag_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/story_name"
            android:layout_below="@id/story_name">
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tag1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="11dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

`onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.tag1.setText("tag name ");
holder.tag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: post the code where you are setting its visibility.

Comment: Is it showing the tags after scrolling ryt???

Comment: Actually i am not not hiding the tags..

Comment: Then what do you mean by this line : " I am clearing the container layout and setvisiblilty to VISIBLE in onbindviewholder." Please post the code for your onBindViewHolder.

Comment: post your recylerview adapter

Comment: my rounded text view is visible always. I didnt clear the parent layout.